# Generate all Possible Unique Combinations of two Excel Columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following simplified data set which I need to create a unique list from and transpose the data from column B at the same time. I think I need to use INDEX, but I am unsure on the correct syntax for this scenario.

The data in column B is delimited by a space.

This is what my data looks like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Column A       |      Column B    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       AA BB      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       BB CC      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       DD EE      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Required result

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Column A       |      Column B    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         AA       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         BB       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         BB       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         CC       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         DD       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         EE       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: If unique, why does ***BB*** appear **twice** in the output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your output table given your input table, you can use Power Query, from the UI, in just a few steps:

- Split Column B by the `space` delimiter.
- Select Column A and then select to `unpivot other columns`
- Delete the extra column `Attribute` that appears when you unpivot.

This is the `M` code for that operation

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column2.1", "Column2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column2.1", type text}, {"Column2.2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

And the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Ron Rosenfeld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997768/1164465) unpivots the data as the OP indicated by the required result.

If you need to create all combinations of data from two columns (rather than unpivoting), normalize the data by placing each set of values in its own column. In this example, Column B has two data entries per cell, which can be split using `Data > Text to Columns`. To work with unique entries, either use the standard Excel tool `Data > Remove Duplicates`, or in Excel Power Query Editor, right click the data column header and click `Remove Duplicates`.

Create separate queries for each column to be included in the combinations. By adding a custom column with a formula referring to the first data query, Power Query will perform a **Full Outer Join** across the two columns resulting in all combinations.

## Final Table Result

[image: Final data table]

---

## Step 1: Data > Text to Columns

(a) Select Column B. In the ribbon, go to Data > Text to Columns.

[image: Excel data table]

[image: Data > Text to Columns]

---

(b) Split the data on the appropriate delimiter (Space, Tab, etc.).

[image: Select delimiter]

---

## Step 2: Combine data and remove duplicates

(a) Cut data from Column C and paste into Column B

[image: Three columns of data]

(b) Paste Column C data into Column B.

[image: Combined column data]

(c) Select Column B and then click Data > Remove Duplicates

[image: Remove duplicates]

(d) If warning pops up about data found next to selection, click "Continue with the current selection"

[image: Remove duplicates warning]

(e) Select checkbox for Column B and click OK.

[image: Select columns to remove duplicates]

## Step 3: Create data query for Column A

(a) Select Column A and click Data > From Table/Range

[image: Data - From Table/Range]

(b) Query Settings > PROPERTIES > Name and enter name "ColumnA"

(c) Home > Close & Load > Close & Load To...

(d) Select: Only Create Connection

[image: Query Settings - enter name]

## Step 4: Create data query for Column B

(a) Select Column B

(b) Data > From Table/Range

[image: Column B data query]

(c) Query Settings > PROPERTIES > Name and enter name "ColumnB"

(d) Add Column > Custom Column

[image: Add Column > Custom Column]

(e) New column name: Combinations

(f) Custom column formula: =ColumnA

[image: Custom column formula]

(g) Expand the new "Combinations" column (icon with left/right arrows)

[image: Expand new Combinations column]

(h) Drag the "Combinations" column to the left side

(i) Home > Close & Load

## Step 5: Sort the output data table

[image: Sort data]